# jQuery intellisense in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Tags: jquery

I am really fed up of searching about jQuery intellisense in Visual Studio 2017.
Please someone tell me the real working solution.
I am using jQuery 3.1.1 in VS 2017 Enterprise.
I have manipulated all the possible options in VS, yet no result.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution myself !

Go to

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Language Services > General

and uncheck "Enable the new JavaScript language service"

Click OK and restart your VS 2017..
Thats IT !!!

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

1. Install jquery.TypeScript.DefinetelyTypes v3.1.2 from Nuget
   If it did not work, then
2. Drag jquery.d.ts from the Script / typings / jquery / folder to any open View.cshtml file

Done!